# Content profile fields not showing up on user registration page

Tags: 6, users

I have created content profile fields that I would like to appear on the user registration form. I am using drupal_render to render these fields on a custom user registration page but they are not appearing. However the other non content profile fields are appearing. Any ideas as to what I could possibly be doing wrong?

I am using Drupal 6.26

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields added in the Content profile will appears in user registration page once you check the check box " use on registration".

You can add default profile fields in admin settings-> user management->profile to show in user registration page.

Instead the uses of Content profile fields here can control for specific role by giving permission but profiles fields in user settings are default for all user registration form .

You can render the fields in custom user registration tpl page by this

drupal_render($form['CATEGORY CHOOSED WHILE CREATING FIELD']['PROFILE FIELD']);

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the fields when you create a user as admin (admin/user/user/create)? If so, this means that permissions are not properly assigned to authenticated users to create those fields. So you need to go to permissions page and edit permissions to each new field that you have created on profile node type.

Answer (score 0):

To appear content profile in user registration form, edit your content profile content type. Choose "content Profile' Tab and choose 'Use on Registration' check box and save.

[image]